# express-session unable to set connect.sid cookie in production

Tags: node.js, nginx, cookies, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, express-session

App is using postgres pool to store sessions. Worked up until the application was monolithic and requests were being routed through reverse-proxy.
But now it's its own service deployed to **production** on Elastic Beanstalk and is not behaving the desired way.

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));

var sess = {
    store: new (connectPgSimple(session))({ pool: db.pool }),
    cookie: { 
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: false
    },
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}

// Trust first proxy for production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1) 
    sess.cookie.secure = true
}

app.use(session(sess));
```

Also added the `withCredentials: *true*` to all requests from client.

It seems to be that the `connect.sid`  session cookie only gets set when the incoming request is proxied to the express server.
I tried the variation of config with express-session to trust the proxy and it still does not create the required cookie.

[Sample response for a POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXe2Q.png)
You can see the response sending the Set-Cookie header back when I check *Application* > *Storage* > *Cookies* I don't see the `connect.sid` cookie

Comment: Your browser probably considers the session cookie a third-party cookie and therefore blocks it.

Comment: That's why I set the allowed origin flag in the CORS configuration in the first line.

Comment: The one has got nothing to do with other. To avoid third-party cookie issues, both your frontend and backend must come from the same top-level domain. If one comes from localhost, so must the other.

Comment: So the withCredentials flag in the front-end requests should be "same-origin" instead of "include"? And the CORS config has to allow requests from the *.TOP_LVL_DOMAIN.com?

Comment: You cannot use `withCredentials: "same-origin"`, because your backend is _not_ the same origin as your frontend. And it need not be, only the _top-level domain_ (the last two segments) must be the same, for example, `frontend.mydomain.com` and `backend.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was in nginx https proxy and adding X-Forwarded-Proto header in config:

```
location / {
  ....
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is experiencing the issue of `express-session unable to set connect.sid cookie`. Also, you can check if your `'saveUninitialized': true,` is `true` which means that since if put 'saveUninitialized': false, no cookie will get set since there is nothing causing the cookie to ever get set.